# YUI rich text editor broken on latest Firefox

Tags: javascript, yui

Well, it been few days I'm observing that YUI 2.9 rich text editor is grayed out in latest Firefox version 58.

As per few Stackoverflow links I tried to patched the YUI library javascript files but most of them are for fixing similar IE issues in the past.

Could anyone please share some experiences with similar sort of things?

Comment: Somebody blindly down voted this post and then somebody helped me to point out the exact thing. If people can not help or don't want to why do they down vote that too without a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bumped into that too. See [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1418639)

You can just monkey patch the `_setInitialContent` method to remove FF special casing.

The following worked for me (`SimpleHTMLEditor` is my subclass of the editor):

```
SimpleHTMLEditor.prototype._setInitialContent = function (raw) {
    YAHOO.log('Populating editor body with contents of the text area', 'info', 'SimpleEditor');

    var value = ((this._textarea) ? this.get('element').value : this.get('element').innerHTML),
        doc = null;

    if (value === '') {
        value = '<br>';
    }

    var html = Lang.substitute(this.get('html'), {
        TITLE: this.STR_TITLE,
        CONTENT: this._cleanIncomingHTML(value),
        CSS: this.get('css'),
        HIDDEN_CSS: ((this.get('hiddencss')) ? this.get('hiddencss') : '/* No Hidden CSS */'),
        EXTRA_CSS: ((this.get('extracss')) ? this.get('extracss') : '/* No Extra CSS */')
    }),
        check = true;

    html = html.replace(/RIGHT_BRACKET/gi, '{');
    html = html.replace(/LEFT_BRACKET/gi, '}');

    if (document.compatMode != 'BackCompat') {
        YAHOO.log('Adding Doctype to editable area', 'info', 'SimpleEditor');
        html = this._docType + "\n" + html;
    } else {
        YAHOO.log('DocType skipped because we are in BackCompat Mode.', 'warn', 'SimpleEditor');
    }

    try {
        //Adobe AIR Code
        if (this.browser.air) {
            doc = this._getDoc().implementation.createHTMLDocument();
            var origDoc = this._getDoc();
            origDoc.open();
            origDoc.close();
            doc.open();
            doc.write(html);
            doc.close();
            var node = origDoc.importNode(doc.getElementsByTagName("html")[0], true);
            origDoc.replaceChild(node, origDoc.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]);
            origDoc.body._rteLoaded = true;
        } else {
            doc = this._getDoc();
            doc.open();
            doc.write(html);
            doc.close();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        YAHOO.log('Setting doc failed.. (_setInitialContent)', 'error', 'SimpleEditor');
        //Safari will only be here if we are hidden
        check = false;
    }
    this.get('iframe').setStyle('visibility', '');
    if (check) {
        this._checkLoaded(raw);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey many thanks for pointing out the fix. But could you please tell me the change inside `_setInitialContent`? I have tried the to remove the or check `(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox/1.5') != -1)` and else statement `this.get('iframe').get('element').src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);`, but nothing helped. And yes I'm editing `yui/editor/editor.js` file.

Comment: Okay. So you subclassed editor class. I'm trying to edit yui/editor/editor.js directly. I can see you don't have the `if (this.browser.ie || this.browser.webkit || this.browser.opera || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox/1.5') != -1)) {` before try-catch.

Comment: Basically the thing is you have omitted the code for appending **data:** into iframe which is the case with original code: `this.get('iframe').get('element').src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);` But unfortunately the same is not working for me. Any clues?

Comment: Ok. It worked!! There were some `patch` folder inside my server's yui folder. It seems that some developer has already patched the YUI earlier and no longer uses the original yui/editor/editor-min.js file.